# How can I count the number of white pixels in a binary image with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I count the number of white pixels in a binary image with MATLAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function [NNZ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nnz.html) should do the trick, since "white" is represented as 1 and "black" as 0 in a binary image `img`:

```
nWhite = nnz(img);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to dispaly this variable on the screen using subplot ?

Comment: @AZIRAR: I'm not sure what you're asking for, but if you want to display the number of white pixels along with the image, you could do the following: `imshow(img); title(['Number of white pixels: ' int2str(nnz(img))]);`